# using datatables for non-table layouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

So I'd like to use datatables such that each "row" looks like this (or at least has this general structure):

[image]

For reference here's the HTML I used to create that:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">joe bob</td>
</tr><tr>
<td rowspan="4">pic</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>DOB: 1/1/1970</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Gender: M</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Phone: 111-111-1111</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Anyway, how might I achieve this with datatables? It seems to me that datatables returns a single `<tr>` but the HTML I used to produce the above has a whole bunch of `<tr>`'s.

I'd like to use datatables for it's ajaxified pagination and searching and for a consistent look and feel with other tables on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this in your datatable init code(untested):

```
'aoColumns': [
   'mRender': function (data, type, full) {
    return '<table border=\'1\' cellspacing=\'1\' cellpadding=\'1\'>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td colspan=\'2\'>' + full[0] +'</td>' +
    '</tr><tr>' +
    '<td rowspan=\'4\'>' + full[1] +'</td>' +
    '</tr><tr>' +
    '<td>DOB: ' + full[2] +'</td>' +
    '</tr><tr>' +
    '<td>Gender: ' + full[3] +'</td>' +
    '</tr><tr>' +
    '<td>Phone: ' + full[4] +'</td>' +
    </tr>';
    </table>
   }
```

This way you're explicitly defining the row output. This would produce an 'inner' table within each datatable row, which may not be what you want.  You might be able to create the inner layout using css instead of tables, but the idea would be the same.  You could use a templating system like jsRender to make it a bit cleaner too.